# How to find advanced descriptive grammars written by PhDs in linguistics?

Tags: grammar

I'll exemplify with Spanish. I'm not seeking books like

- John Butt, Carmen Benjamin's [*A New Reference Grammar of Modern Spanish*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/113812401X), now in its 2018 6 ed.
- [*Academia Real's Gramática de la lengua española, 2005 and Esbozo de una nueva gramática de la lengua española, 1973*](https://old.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/9t1mlw/largest_grammar_book_in_each_foreign_language/e8u4cnn/).

Rather, I yen for something like [*The Structure of Modern Standard French: A Student Grammar*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01JXSSZUQ) (2016), by [Maj-Britt Mosegaard Hansen](https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/maj-britt.mosegaardhansen.html) who

1. holds a PhD in linguistics and
2. uses linguistics to describe grammar.

> Written primarily for those readers who have an intermediate to advanced knowledge of French, this book nevertheless can be very useful to those who like the reviewer have been studying French intensely but who could be still classified as beginner/intermediate. Even though the book does not presuppose knowledge of linguistics, readers who have such knowledge, even if not advanced, will be better able to appreciate the analysis in the book. Some readers may be annoyed at the lack of English translation for the many examples given, but this lack can also force readers to concentrate more on working out the translations themselves.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Language Learning Stack Exchange. Could you please edit this question to focus on a single language that you are interested in? If you are interested in this type of grammar for more than one language, please post one question per language.

Comment: Could you also explain what you mean by "uses linguistics to describe grammar"? What sort of linguistics did you find in *The Structure of Modern Standard French* (which apparently "does not presuppose knowledge of linguistics") that you missed in the first two examples?

Comment: Find universities that teach linguistics and the professors. Most of them have written articles if not books....or Go to the Library of Congress website. Have fun.